# Sequential Combination of string from string

Tags: c#, string, combinations, sequence

I am stumped. I wanted to know if any combination in sequence order of the string is available. like for example my string to match is

```
string somevar = "rat";
```

then if an another string contains "rat", "at", "ra" or "r", "a", "t" it should return false.

I can only think of making condition for every single sequence i can manually find. but I am sure there could be some trick to find it easily. I had a look on [Implement a function that prints all possible combinations of the characters in a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28248/implement-a-function-that-prints-all-possible-combinations-of-the-characters-in) but it doesnt do what I want.

I am sorry if this is not very clear but I want to check a condition where

```
 if(somevar == "rat" || somevar == "at" || somevar == "ra" || somevar == "r" || somevar == "a" || somevar == "t")
 {
      \\do something
 }
```

Comment: Last edit invalidate previous requirement. You said "contains" earlier and now you directly compare with set of values.

Comment: @Sinatr: Yeah that was creating the confusion so i removed it. I mean to say. is my last condition should return false. Sorry for all the trouble

Comment: @mybirthname "drastically" - i just had to change a few characters

Comment: @fubo yes but few characters can change the question a lot. From contains to equal the difference is really big in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a method that determines all substrings

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllSubStrings(string input, int length)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length - length + 1; i++)
    {
        yield return input.Substring(i, length);
    }
}
```

then you can just create a list with all combintaions

```
string somevar = "rat";
List<string> subStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < somevar.Length; i++)
{
    subStrings.AddRange(GetAllSubStrings(somevar, i + 1));
}
// subStrings = {"rat", "at", "ra", "r", "a", "t"}
```

and finally check your other string against that list.

**UPDATE to your updated Question:**

```
//check "ra" 
string testItem = "ra";
bool contains = subStrings.Any(x => testItem == x);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check all substrings if it's sufficient that a single char is contained:

```
bool containsAnyChar = somevar.Intersect("rat").Any();
```

That works because a string implements `IEnumerable<char>`(is a collection of characters).

Comment: @mybirthname: `Any` is less efficient if the string is large. It's just a loop so O(n), `Intersect` uses a set based aproach. If the string isn't large it doesn't matter anyway

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes I test it manually with 2 strings with 10k characters(1-10k numbers and 5k -15k numbers) and the difference is really big. I didn't know it, thanks for mention it like I said. I already upvoted you

Answer (score -1):

```
string somevar = "rat";
string anotherString = "rat is there";
bool result = somevar.ToCharArray().Any(ch => anotherString.Contains(ch));
```